# How to pass data from php to javascript with multiple requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I have a website with a search engine that loads the search results via $.ajax just like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "search_engine.php",
        data: 'value=' + search_text,
        cache: false,
        success: function(results){
            $('#search_results').html(results);    
        },
        error: function(){alert("An error occured ")},
    })
```

The php will echo a html table with the variables it got from the database, like:

```
<td class='info'>
     <div class='infoPin'>
          <div class='name'><b><span>$print_name</span></b></div>
          <div class='description'>
               $print_desc
          </div>
     </div>
</td>
```

This is working fine but now I'd like to add markers to the map corresponding to the search results. Although I've never used XML I know that saving an XML file with all the results is an option but my problem is that multiple users with multiple searches can access the site at the same time so this can be a problem right?

At the same time I have so many results that I only load part of them each time and use multiple pages (just like google), making it impossible to echo the data into the page somewhere, and use JavaScript to get the information from the DOM...

So basically, **what I need** is to:

- Get in Javascript the variables I have in php;
- Add markers to Google Maps with those parameters;

**Considering** that:

- The search results can be hundreds of items (hundreds of rows in a table);
- Because of the great number of results only part of them are loaded to the html page but on the map all the markers corresponding to the search should be shown;
- Multiple users can access the website at the same time;

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you just spit out json instead of html, and give the data to a loop that adds the markers using the gmaps api. no major re factoring is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could send JSON data back from PHP when you request the search data. Let's say you have an array in PHP with all the search results. Then you can convert it to a JSON string, so your jQuery ajax success function can convert that to an object and loop over it.

In PHP:

```
$results = array(
    0 => array('name' => 'Res1', 'desc' => 'Desc1', 'longitude' => 52.366, 'latitude' => 4.91),
    1 => array('name' => 'Res2', 'desc' => 'Desc2', 'longitude' => 52.511, 'latitude' => 4.90),
    2 => array('name' => 'Res3', 'desc' => 'Desc3', 'longitude' => 52.753, 'latitude' => 4.92),
);
$json = json_encode($results);
print($json);
```

And in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search_engine.php",
    data: 'value=' + search_text,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(results) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(results);
        if (typeof data === 'object') {
            $('#search_results').empty();
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                console.log(v);
                /* Use the v variable (which contains a result as an object) to fill $('#search_results') with data and reinit maps data with long/lat or address data */
            });
        }
    },
    error: function() { alert("An error occured "); },
});
```

To fill your `#search_results` element, take a look at the [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function of jQuery.

Comment: But imagine the search returns an array with 1000 or more results... This will correspond to 1000+ entries in a JavaScript object in a browser. This will make it run slow right?

Comment: Yes that would make it slow. You should limit those results, I guess that much results will be useless to the user right? You could use pagination for that reason.